# tensorflow : @ symbol

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I saw a code snippet in the tensorflow documentation and couldn't find any info about it
So, what is the role/purpose of the `@` symbol at the code below :

```
x @ tf.transpose(x)
```

Comment: matrix multiplication

Comment: Never occured to me, thank u so much

Comment: Here's the reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul. Search for @ on the page, it's towards the end.

Comment: Also: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/

Comment: Excellent, I'll read it right now

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to post an answer to your question and accept it. I am too lazy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '@' symbol is used as Matrix multiplication and equal to `tf.matmul()`.

Let's understand this with the below example:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], shape=[2, 2])
print(x)  # 2-D tensor

x @ tf.transpose(x) # as @ is a symbol of matrix multiplication
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2]
 [3 4]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 5, 11],
       [11, 25]], dtype=int32)>
```

To verify if this is the same as `tf.matmul()`, check the below code:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], shape=[2, 2])
print(x) 

print(tf.transpose(x)) # which will change row into column and column into row

# Now performing Matrix multiplication
c = tf.matmul(x,tf.transpose(x))    #1*1+2*2 1*3+2*4
c                                   #3*1+4*2 3*3+4*4
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2]
 [3 4]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 3]
 [2 4]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 5, 11],
       [11, 25]], dtype=int32)>
```